# Contabilizar campos conforme forem sendo incluídos com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o formulário abaixo do qual quando clico em **Adicionar mais Pets**, ele inclui perfeitamente. Até aqui está funcionando 100%, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que tenho uma numeração ao lado do título **#1**. Gostaria de que conforme for sendo incluído novos **panels**, fossem sendo numerados: **#1, #2, #3, #N...**

Tentei da seguinte forma:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
<span id="contar">#1</span>  <i class="fa fa-paw fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> DADOS DO PET
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function() {
      novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
      novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
      novoCampo.find('select').val("");      
        if ($("tr.linhas").length < 20) {
            for(i = 0; i < $("tr.linhas").length; i++){
                contar = i + 2;
                $("#contar").append(contar);
            }
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
       }
    });
```

Porém ele numera só no primeiro panel, vejam abaixo quando incluo mais um campo, ou seja, total de 02 campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o JavaScript por este:

```
/*globals jQuery*/
(function($) {
  $(".adicionarCampo").on('click', function() {

    var novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();

    novoCampo.find('input[type="text"]').val("");
    novoCampo.find('select').val("");

    var number = parseInt(novoCampo.find('#contar').text().replace('#', ''));
    novoCampo.find("#contar").html('#' + parseInt(number + 1));

    if ($("tr.linhas").length < 20) {      
      novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Se você perceber, eu fiz algumas pequenas modificações em seu código, por exemplo, **declarei as variáveis**. Essa é uma prática importante no JavaScript.

Sempre preceda uma variável por `var` na sua declaração. Por exemplo, `var i = 1;`.